# Can't load random images

Tags: javascript, arrays, image

I've been trying to get the  cat images displayed in random order from the top array. My click4pics doesn't work with the  code that is shown, I get a message that the images
cannot be found  however when I change the image source to load only one image the function works
Also the rightpath with this?

```js
const cat$Images = [
  { name: "C1", img: "C1.jpg", },
  { name: "C2", img: "C2.jpg", }, 
  { name: "C3", img: "C3.jpg", }, 
  { name: "C4", img: "C4.jpg", },
]
    
let PicturePairs = [
  { name: "C1", img: "C1.jpg", 
    name: "C2", img: "C2.jpg", }, 
];
console.log(PicturePairs)
console.log(cat$Images)    
    
function shuffle(array) {
  let currentIndex = array.length,
      randomIndex;
      
  while(currentIndex != 0) {
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex--;
      
    [array[currentIndex], array[randomIndex]] = [
      array[randomIndex], array[currentIndex]
    ];
  }
}
      
shuffle(cat$Images)
shuffle(PicturePairs)
      
let clickImage = document.querySelector("#button")
clickImage.addEventListener("click",click4pics)

function click4pics(i) {
  let catpics=document.createElement("img")
  catpics.src=`images/${cat$Images[i].img}`;
  catpics.alt = cat$Images.src;
  document.querySelector("#box").appendChild(catpics);
  catpics.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    console.log(e.target.src);
  })
}
    
click4pics(0)
click4pics(1)
click4pics(2)
click4pics(3)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first parameter of any function that is used as an event handler is the "event" itself. So, if you add a console.log(i) at the beginning of the "click4pics" function, then try to click the button, you'll find that he "i" is the event object.
To fix that, you may use a loop instead of passing a parameter.

```
function click4pics() {
  for (let i = 0; i < cat$Images.length; i++) {
    let catpics = document.createElement("img")
    catpics.src = `images/${cat$Images[i].img}`;
    catpics.alt = cat$Images.src;
    document.querySelector("#box").appendChild(catpics);
    catpics.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
      console.log(e.target.src);
    })
  }
}
```

If you aim to re-generate the random images each time the button clicked, then put all the login inside the "click4pics" function. And before regenerating images' elements, make sure that you empty the "#box" first.

```js
    function shuffle(array) {
      let currentIndex = array.length,
        randomIndex;

      while (currentIndex != 0) {

        randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
        currentIndex--;

        [array[currentIndex], array[randomIndex]] = [
          array[randomIndex], array[currentIndex]
        ];
      }

    }

    let clickImage = document.querySelector("#button")
    clickImage.addEventListener("click", click4pics)

    function click4pics() {
      const cat$Images = [
        { name: "C1", img: "C1.jpg", },
        { name: "C2", img: "C2.jpg", },
        { name: "C3", img: "C3.jpg", },
        { name: "C4", img: "C4.jpg", },
      ]

      let PicturePairs = [
        {
          name: "C1", img: "C1.jpg",
          name: "C2", img: "C2.jpg",
        },
      ];

      shuffle(cat$Images)
      shuffle(PicturePairs)

      document.querySelector("#box").innerHTML = ''; // empty it each time

      for (let i = 0; i < cat$Images.length; i++) {
        let catpics = document.createElement("img")
        catpics.src = `images/${cat$Images[i].img}`;
        catpics.alt = cat$Images.src;
        document.querySelector("#box").appendChild(catpics);
        catpics.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
          console.log(e.target.src);
        })
      }
    }

    click4pics()
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
<button id="button">btn</button>
```

If you have issues with the images' paths, Make sure you have a folder called "images" at the same level as your Html file and put the images inside it.

Comment: I also had to change the jpg's to png's